# HTTP call using Salesforce

Tags: httprequest, http, httpresponse

I am trying to rewrite the following **Java** HTTP request in Salesforce.

```
    String apiUrl = "url";
    String wsUser = "YourWSUser";
    String wsPassword = "YourWSPassword";

    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(wsUser, wsPassword);
    provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();


    HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(apiUrl);
    httpRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(paymentRequest.toString(), "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpRequest);
    String paymentResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

This is what I wrote in **APEX**:

```
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    req.setEndpoint(apiUrl);
    req.setMethod('POST');

    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
    String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setBody(generator.getAsString());
    req.setTimeout(60000);


    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

My questions are:

- Is the conversion correct?
- If so any idea why I get a **401** as if my credentials are not set correctly. (knowing that the credentials and end point is correct)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [403 - Forbidden Cannot authenticate user](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116626/403-forbidden-cannot-authenticate-user)

Comment: @VigneshwaranG No, it's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @VigneshwaranG It's a completely different question I am getting here a **401 Unauthorized error code**

Answer (score 3):

```
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
```

This code is not correct. The automatic "toString" method results in a different message than you expect:

```
Blob b = Blob.valueOf('World');
System.debug('Hello '+ b);
```

Output:

> 11:21:43.1 (2562345)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Hello Blob[5]

Instead, you do want to use a regular string:

```
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(username + ':' + password);
```

---

As an aside, you can't provide a Body when method is set to GET. The platform will implicitly coerce the request to a POST instead. You should always make sure you're using the correct HTTP verb, because some servers will throw random fits if you don't follow the allowed verbs/request style.

Comment: I got that the blob is different.. but I took my code from Salesforce .. from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm)

Anyways I will change and give it a try.

Comment: @raym0nd Hmmm... Looks like I was indeed wrong, after all. What's disturbing though is that the salesforce code shouldn't be wrong (but probably is). Further investigation is necessary. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: I changed it to POST, it still has the same issue. Btw my username and passwords are both in string...